# Transcript file from MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, onedrive, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams, videojs-transcript

I have searched a lot to get transcript file from MS Team meet. I have read documentation of MS Stream but as per their announcements, meet video will y default going to store in One drive instead of MS Stream from Q1 2021.

Then I have read about Microsoft flow to set trigger to get the Meet Url atleast as a webhook. That I succeeded. Now My main purpose is to get transcript file of meets video along with who said what with names.

I tried everything i.e MS Stream, Ms Teams, One drive, Flow. But didn't find anything.

Any workaround to get transcript file from meets video along with who said what with name.

This I want through webhook. Zoom is providing this service from their UI. It is pretty straightforward in zoom.

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Our team is working on this actively and we don't have any ETA to share when it will be in GA.

Comment: When will we get this update? @VaraPrasad-MSFT

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT  any update here.?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the transcript you will need to build a MS Teams app/bot that is added to each call so it knows when to retrieve the transcription at the end of the call, and can access the graph api.

Examples of building a bot: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore

The transcription API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/system-messages#call-transcript